# Read all columns in excel

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

How do I read an Excel spreadsheet having blank column. I have spreadsheet in below format:

[image]

I am trying to read the excel file with this code:

```
 string query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";
 using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connString))
  {
    connection.Open();
   OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
   OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
 while (reader.Read())
     {
       //Do something
     }
}
```

But it reads data of only the starting 2 columns and not the remaining. How do I read data of all columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried OleDbDataAdapter to fill DataTable and displayed in DataGridView.
Your sql can retrive all the data.
However, your excel contains **duplicate column names**. After read by sql, column name was added **suffix** such as column**1**. So maybe in your //Do something statement, you can try such column names.

[image: my test data]
[image: my test result]

Comment: Is there any way to get all column names (may be duplicate names) from excel without suffixing anything ?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with data connections in Excel a while ago. The following query should do the trick:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A:E]";
```

You should just specify the range you would like to use.